# setting up docker with python 3.9 + poetry getting 'does not contain any element'

Tags: python, docker, python-poetry

I am trying to setup docker for local dev and i keep getting "does not contain any element" when i try to use poetry with docker. Originally I used the requirement.txt, however i would prefer it to have poetry because where i work we have a pyserver which we need to pull some of the .wh from.

So i am trying to keep it basic. This my structure and some basic code

[image]

-------------------main.py-------------

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello, World!"}
```

----------------------uvicorn_conf.py------

```
from uvicorn.workers import UvicornWorker
bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"
workers = 4
worker_class = UvicornWorker
```

-----------Dockerfile-------

```
FROM python:3.9

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the entire project directory to the container
COPY . .

# Install Poetry and project dependencies
RUN pip install poetry
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false
RUN poetry install --no-dev

# Start the server
CMD ["poetry", "run", "start"]
```

---------pyproject.toml------

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "my-app"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["py_dev <test@testing.com>"]
readme = "README.md"
packages = [{include = "my_app"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
fastapi = "^0.95.1"
uvicorn = "^0.21.1"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
start = "uvicorn my_app.main:app --config uvicorn_conf.py"
```

And every time i run build, I get this error. [image]
I am not sure how to fix this. Any advice or direction on how to get it working would be brilliant. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "_Originally I used the requirement.txt, however i would prefer it to have poetry because where i work we have a pyserver which we need to pull some of the .wh from._" I must say I do not follow the logic.You could still use *pip* and a `requirements.txt` file if you have a custom package index server.

Comment: @sinoroc the one thing i dont like about the requirements is that if you dont delete docker... packages that you dont need anymore maybe linger around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "my_app" directory in the screenshot you posted, so you should update `"my_app"` to `"app"` in your `pyproject.toml`:

```
packages = [{include = "app"}]
```

See https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#packages for more info.

Comment: Thank that fixed but now i have another problem.. when i run it i get this.

  File "<string>", line 1
    import sys; from importlib import import_module; sys.argv = ['/usr/local/bin/start']; sys.exit(import_module('uvicorn app.main').app --config uvicorn_conf.py())
                                                                                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax